# Getting title of a category that has id 80

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT title FROM #__categories WHERE id = 80'); 
$category = $db->loadResult();
echo $category;
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not return the title of category with id 80?

and/or is there a better way of doing this? I have an item that shows the id but not the name/title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following which uses Joomla 2.5 coding standards:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);   
$query->select('title')
  ->from('#__categories')
  ->where('id = 80');   
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

echo $result;
```

As nibra mentioned, you can also check to see if it exists like so:

```
if($result){
    echo $result;
}
else {
    echo "title with this ID was not found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, if there is a category with the id `80`. So

- if `$category` is null, there is no such category;
- if `$category` is something else, that *is* the title of your category.

Beide that, the better way to access the database in Joomla! is as Lodder pointed out.

Comment: Thank you but it does not work but Lodder's code works, I'll use that format from now on :P

Comment: @DoctorArnar - nibra does mate a good point which might not be needed in this case, but is always good for practices in the future, I have updated my answer which a little example.